# playframework 2.3.x heap size

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

Is there a way to set -Xmx when i start the application with "./activator start"

I tried (not working):

```
./activator start -J-Xmx2g

./activator -mem 2048 start

_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2g" ./activator  start
```

It says

> "Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2g"

but still not working.

Also tried various values in `build.sbt` and `application.conf` - no luck

The only way i could make it work was to use 
"stage" and pass `-Xmx2g` to the generated shell script, which is fine, but it doesn't detach the console.

I think I tried all I found on google but still no luck.
I would like to pass `-Xmx` to the `activator start` somehow.

Answer (score 2):

First define an environment variable with your JVM parameters named `_JAVA_OPTIONS`

> `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2048m"`

and then try the `play start` or use the `activator`.

Comment: This does not work. The effect is completely the same as _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2g" ./activator start . One does not need to export a variable if you can pass it before the actual command.

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution. There is some bug in activator shell script, so passing -J-Xmx argument does not remove default mem options. To change mem parameter have a look at your activator script (/usr/local/bin/activator) and have a look how mem parameters are added. Also notice that passing -v argument will print final command to lunch java. Working solution on linux for me is this:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2700m";activator -v
# Executing command line:
java
-Dactivator.home=/usr/local/bin
-Xmx2700m
-jar
/usr/local/bin/activator-launch-1.3.2.jar
```

Examples of not working solution:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2048m";activator -J-Xmx2700m -J-Xms1024m -v
# Executing command line:
java
-Dactivator.home=/usr/local/bin
-Xmx2700m
-Xmx2700m
-Xms1024m
-jar
/usr/local/bin/activator-launch-1.3.2.jar
```

Also not working:

```
activator -J-Xmx2700m -J-Xms1024m -v
# Executing command line:
java
-Dactivator.home=/usr/local/bin
-Xmx2700m
-Xmx2700m
-Xms1024m
-jar
/usr/local/bin/activator-launch-1.3.2.jar
```

Comment: If you get some out of memory in playframework when developing a lot, you can try to add "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m" parameter to make "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace" go away for a little bit longer (there is an issue for memory leak https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3799).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify both, min and max heap size, try this:

```
activator -J-Xmx2048m -J-Xms2048m start
```

Comment: no luck :(

Still seeing  java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m in the process list

Comment: Yeah, I see that too but heap size is 2gigs. Check with jvisualvm.